# show div depending on select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, hide, show

Oh help, I've tried it a million different ways yet it still does not work: If you select update or final from a select/option box, it should show the div that has an input field in it. It only does what the default shows in the switch statement. Of course, it's only after a selection is made that I want it to determine whether it shows the input field or not.

in head section...

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('#needfilenum').hide();  
var optionValue = $("#needtoshow").val();  

switch (optionValue)  
{  
case 'update':  
$("#needfilenum").show();
break;  

case 'final':  
$("#needfilenum").show();  
break;  
default:  
$("#needfilenum").hide();  
break;  
    }
});
//});

'<select id="needtoshow" >  
<option id="dfaut" value="0">Select Something</option>
<option id="update" value="update">Update</option>
<option id="final" value="final">Final</option>
<option id="allergy"value="allergy">Vegan</option>  
</select>
<div id="needfilenum"  style="background:#f00;">  
<input type="text" name="wharever"   />
</div>
```

I can change the default on the switch and that seems to dictate what it shows
also tried

```
//  $("#needtoshow").change(function() {  

//      switch ($(this).val())
```

Comment: show your code using code format

Comment: well i thought i followed the directions to post
i'll repost

Comment: Notice: you can't give id's to <option> elements, they only get selected, value, and label... see w3.org

Comment: thank you for the help.  that was a last ditch hope... saw it and tried it!

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the div show and hide when the drop-down changes, you need to bind to the change event, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#needfilenum').hide();

  $('#needtoshow').bind('change', function() {
    var optionValue = $("#needtoshow").val();

    switch (optionValue)
    {
      case 'update':
      case 'final':
        $("#needfilenum").show();
        break;

      default:
        $("#needfilenum").hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

In your code, the switch statement runs only once when the page first loads.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to bind an event listener on your select box. ([change event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change))
So you would have something along the lines of:

```
$("#oldfilenum").change(function() {
  var optionValue = $(this).val();
  switch (optionValue) { 
    case 'update': 
      $("#needfilenum").show(); 
      break; 
    case 'final ': 
      $("#needfilenum").show(); 
      break; 
    default: 
      $("#needfilenum").hide(); 
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var selectBox = $("#oldfilenum"), magicDiv = $("#needfilenum");
selectBox.bind("change", function() {
    var val = this.value;
    if (val === "update" || val === "final") {
        magicDiv.show();
    } else {
        magicDiv.hide();
    }
});
```

Of course you can use `switch` instead, or have a `[]` of acceptable values and do `it.indexOf(val) > -1` or whatever.

As Victor commented on another answer, `change` fires on `blur` in MSIE, so you may want to use another [event](http://docs.jquery.com/Events) if that is an issue, perhaps `mouseup`.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the [change()](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) event.  Attach that to your `<select>` and then perform your logic.

Comment: Be very very careful with change events. They behave differently in IE and Firefox (IE waits till blur to fire it). For sure in radiobuttons and checkboxes, don't know if also for selects.

Answer (score 0):

Your checking function runs only once, and not every time you change the select field. You need to put an onchange handler into the select field:

```
<select id="needtoshow" onchange="your_function_name_here()">
```

Comment: no no no bad habit, you should avoid that inline javascripting.